# Синонимизировать [пагинации]!

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

По пагинации есть целый зоопарк синонимов (отсортировано по популярности):

- [pagination](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination) — 98 вопросов,
- [page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/page) — 20 вопросов,
- [постраничный-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) — 10 вопросов,
- [paging](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paging) — 8 вопросов,
- [пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) — 2 вопроса.

У нас принятно основными делать русскоязычные метки. Поэтому из всех вариантов остаются только [постраничный-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) или [пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f). Исконно русское название — [постраничный-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4), но для тех, кто в основном работает с англоязычной литературой, привычней будет [пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: [page] может быть не в роли синонима [pagination]

Comment: А куда засунуть paging как способ управления виртуальной памятью?

Comment: @АндрейNOP практика показывает, что может. Почти во всех вопросах метка соответствует именно пагинации. А что ещё можно делать у нас на сайт с [tag:page], чтобы это ещё было по теме и метка не была "притянута за уши"?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Завести отдельную метку для этого случая типа [tag:memory-paging] или что-то в этом роде и добавить качественное руководство. Сейчас её лепят именно так как я и предлагаю синонимизировать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Кстати на enSO, руководство [tag:paging] именно так и описано "A memory-management technique…" и эти метки не синонимы с [tag:pagination]. Но намного чаще использование именно так 
как я и предалагаю синонимизировать.

Answer (score 5):

Основной делаем [пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) как дословную кальку с привычного и популярного английского слова [pagination](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination).

Comment: Не люблю транслитерацию...

Comment: @Qwertiy Посмотрим результаты голосования, слово достаточно часто употребимое и вроде пишут, что произошло от латинского *pagina* https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F. Но в любом случае лучше хоть как-то синонимизировать, чем оставить висеть отдельно.

Comment: да, согласен, что надо синонимизировать. Просто мне нравятся либо чисто русский вариант, либо чисто английский, а не транслит.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сделаете синонимизацию в какую-либо сторону? Это вариант набрал больше голосов "за", но тут перевесы везде незначительные, если честно. В любом случае, всегда можно будет изменить основную метку.

Answer (score 5):

А как насчёт основной [pagination](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination)? Чтоб не транслитом была, а как положено.

Comment: Я за английские названия, в одной из голосовалок [слайдер] было решено заменять на [slider], но Vadim Ovchinnikov продолжает настаивать на русских названиях.

Answer (score 4):

Основной делаем [постраничный-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4), чтобы исконно русские названия были основными метками.